# Apache Superset - How to use Geospatial charts as filter?

Tags: apache-superset

I have created a dashboard using Apache Superset (superset-helm-chart-0.10.5). It contains two charts (table and deck.gl Polygon) as shown in below image.

[image: Superset-Dashboard]

I have enabled cross-filters in config.py, to use charts as interactive filters. When I click a row from 'table' chart, the corresponding data is filtered on map as shown below.

[image: Superset-Dashboard-Filter]

Similarly, I would like to use the map as a filter (i.e.) when I select a polygon from chart, the corresponding row should be highlighted/ filtered.

This is not happening by default. Kindly let me know if this functionality is available in superset.

And also, kindly let me know if Superset supports
"Drawing tools (rectangle, square, circle etc..) to select features within a map extent, based on which the other dashboard elements are updated".